Hydration Error - Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <a>
In the footer component of my website, there is some line that causes the hydration error on initial render and whenever I reload the page, The error looks like this,
Hydration error
It is occurring because of footer component code which is,
function Footer() {
    const settings = {
        responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: false,
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 6000,
                mobileFirst: true,
        
              }
            }
          ]
        };
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <>
        <div className='col-12 footer'>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="col-12 title text-white text-center mb-60">
                    <h2 className="title-text mb-40">Join the community</h2>
                    <div className="row justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-auto">
                            <img
                                width="30px"
                                className="img-fluid"
                                src={images.instagram.default.src}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-auto">
                            <h4 className="mb-0 fw-bold">#musclefueluae</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 mb-80 d-none d-lg-block">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-3 px-4">
                            <InstaFeedCard/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-3 px-4">
                            <InstaFeedCard/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-3 px-4">
                            <InstaFeedCard/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-3 px-4">
                            <InstaFeedCard/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div className="col-12 mb-80 d-lg-none">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <Slider {...settings}>
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <InstaFeedCard/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <InstaFeedCard/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <InstaFeedCard/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <InstaFeedCard/>
                                </div>
                            </Slider>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr className="border-white m-0"/>
                <div className="col-12 menu d-none d-lg-block">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md">
                            <img
                                className="logo img-fluid"
                                src={images.logoBg.default.src}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md d-none d-lg-block">
                            <h6 className="fw-semibold text-white mb-3">Company</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/">Home</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/about">About us</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/contact-us">Contact us</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/frequently-asked-questions">FAQs</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md d-none d-lg-block">
                            <h6 className="fw-semibold text-white mb-3">Healthy Eating</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/meal-plans">Meal Plans</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/menu">Alacarte Menu</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/delivery-locations">Delivery Location</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/recommended-plans">Recommended plans</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md d-none d-lg-block">
                            <h6 className="fw-semibold text-white mb-3">Locations</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/">Meal Plans in AbuDhabi</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/">Meal Plans in Dubai</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md d-none d-lg-block">
                            <h6 className="fw-semibold text-white mb-3">Know more</h6>
                            <ul className="mb-4">
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/terms-and-conditions" target="_blank">Terms & conditions</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Link href="/">Privacy policy</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div className="col-12 social-links">
                                <Link href="https://www.instagram.com/musclefueluae/?hl=en" target='_blank'>
                                    <img
                                        width="24px"
                                        className="img-fluid"
                                        src={images.instagram.default.src}
                                    />
                                </Link>
                                <Link href="https://www.facebook.com/MuscleFuelUAEs/" target='_blank'>
                                <img
                                    width="24px"
                                    className="img-fluid"
                                    src={images.facebook.default.src}
                                />
                                </Link>
                                <Link href="">
                                <img
                                    width="24px"
                                    className="img-fluid"
                                    src={images.twitter.default.src}
                                />
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 text-center copyright d-none d-lg-block">
                    <p className="mb-0 text-grey">copyright@2023 MusclefuelUAE  |   Website designed, developed & maintained by qualwebs</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

I tried changing Link tags to anchor tags and checked the structure but it didn't work. The error appeared whenever i reloaded the page or on initial render. And there is no server side rendering here.

The issue is resolved !! It was actually on app.js where I imported the component like this, const Footer = dynamic(() => import('@/src/component/layout/footer'), { ssr: false }). and It didnt threw any error, refer to this documentation of https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#skipping-ssr
